# meteor.js - is it possible to maintain css changes caused by javascript in reactive templates?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template hooked up to a data source that is changing pretty often, and I want that template to be able to be toggled by the user. I have a button in a parent template that triggers an animation on another template to slide off the screen... but as soon as that second template's data changes, the template updates and re-renders with the original css, i.e. it is displayed again when it should be hidden. To fix this, I tried adding a callback function to the animation function to set a session variable like Session.set("showData", false), and updated that template to only show if that session variable is true. This works great for HIDING it, the animation plays and it stays hidden, but I can't figure out how to make it display again with a slide-in animation. If I set that session variable to true it will re-render again instantly, with the original css and giving me no time to have a slide in animation.

Here is the html/templates:

```
//the two templates are called inside <body>
{{> controls}}
<div class="sidebar">
  {{> dataview}}
</div>

<template name="controls">
<div id="controls">
  <a class="toggle button">Hide Dataview</a>
</div>
</template>

<template name="dataview">
{{#if show}}
<div id="mydata">
  <ul>
  {{#each somedata}}
    //any data in here
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

And the related js:

```
Template.controls.events({
  'click .toggle': function(e) {
    //using an animation library but I would expect the same behaviour with jquery's .animate or simply modifying the css with vanilla js
    TweenLite.set($('.sidebar'), {perspective:400});
    TweenLite.to($('#mydata'), 0.5, {rotationY:90, transformOrigin:"right top", onComplete:toggleView});
  }
});

function toggleView () {
  Session.set("showData", false);
}

Template.dataview.show = function() {
  //this is initialized as true in meteor.startup
  return Session.get("showData")
}
```

Does that make sense? Am I going about this the wrong way? I feel like template.*mytemplate*.preserve may be what I need but I tried that and I either implemented it incorrectly or it didn't do what I was hoping. Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a side effect of the current rendering engine, so the short answer is no, you can't reliably do this for the exact reasons you've described.

The good news is Meteor is rewriting their rendering engine to support fine-grained DOM updates, jQuery integration among other things! This will be released with 1.0, which is scheduled for this quarter.

You can read more about it here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview

The Google Groups discussion about it:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/gHSSlyxifec

Try it out from the "template-engine-preview-release-10.1" branch:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/release/template-engine-preview-release-10.1

Meteor roadmap:

https://trello.com/b/hjBDflxp/meteor-roadmap